# Ford DuraTorq TDCi EGR system (Euro4) operation, blanking

Tags: ford, electronic-control-module, egr, tdci

Specifically the 2008-on (Euro-4 emissions compliant) 2.2 diesel as fitted to Jaguar X-Type (and Mondeo, Transit, etc.) but I suspect the entire DuraTorq family are the same:

I've seen EGR blanking kits for these, the early (pre-2008) ones blank the EGR totally, the later ones have a ~10mm hole drilled to allow some flow as, apparently, the ECU detects the blanking and throws a fault code.

My question is: How does it detect this, and can it be fooled so the EGR can be totally blanked off?

*I'm aware of the implications (positive and negative) of blanking the EGR.*

Answer (score 1):

Fords use a differential pressure sensor on the EGR system to detect operation. There are two hoses (one with a slight restriction) coming off the EGR tube and the DPFE sensor. If the sensor doesn't detect a change in pressure when the egr solenoid is commanded it will set a low or no flow code. If the sensor is removed it'll set a circuit code.

I'd assume the only way to prevent a MIL would be to turn off the monitor in the PCM but I'd also suspect that turning off the monitor would cause you to fail an emissions test if they run a monitor check during inspection.

Comment: Thanks, any finer detail on the sensor, system plumbing etc.? I've not found any technical manuals for the car so far.